# Multi-threaded scheduled jobs in JBoss 7.1

Tags: multithreading, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, job-scheduling

I have previously scheduled a periodic batch job with JMX scheduling using *org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler* in JBoss 5. This support is removed in JBoss 7.1.

The only alternative I have found is the @schedule annotation for EJBs. However, a job running inside a EJB is not allowed to start threads. It is essential to run this batch import job in several parallel threads to use the hardware resources more efficiently, saving hours of processing.

How do I schedule a job in JBoss 7.1 that can invoke EJBs from several threads in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally the way to go when parallel execution is required, is using MDBs. (By traditionally I have in mind the asynchronous invocations, but that is a new EJB 3.1 feature I think, so not for JBoss 7.1.)

An outline of the setup is as follows:

1. A `@Schedule`'d EJB that triggers the batch process.
2. A queue.
3. A MDB listening to this queue. The MDB should be configured to run as many instances (effectively threads) as you would in the old job.
4. A message object that will be inserted in the queue and represent a job to be executed by the MDB.

When the `@Schedule`'d EJB is triggered, it will push the appropriate number of job messages to the queue. These will be delivered and executed in parallel to the MDB instances by the container.

As a (probably indifferent) bonus, the code gets to be standards compilant and not dependent on a specific application server API.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably correct but this seems like serious overkill for the task at hand.

Comment: I'm not sure it is indeed, but you may be right. In essence you would have to refactor your existing code to run as or be called by the MDB (this shouldn't be big). Add the queue (there should be plenty of documentation on that). And write the `@Schedule`'d EJB (not big either). Then again its your code and you know better...

Comment: In my case the handling cannot be completely parallel so I must have code that manages the queue, probably by having multiple queues (import of files that depend on each other must be in sequence, others may be in parallel). But my main gripe is that installing and maintaining a queue can be quite complicated when it comes to operations and tuning. Anyway, this is probably the reason why lighter containers than EJB are so popular these days :) Thanks.